# How to get a unique match pair from many tables?

Tags: sql-server, database

I want to create a unique pair with one mentor and one mentee. I only want to have a mentor in only one pair and a mentee to belong to only one pair.

These are the tables that I have now involved in the pair:

```
create table member(
    MemberID int not null primary key Identity (1,1),
    MemberFName varchar(255),
    MemberLName varchar(255),
    MemberStreet varchar(255),
    MemberCity varchar(255),
    MemberState varchar(20),
    MemberZip varchar(10),
    MemberPhone bigint,
    MemberEmail varchar(255),
    MemberDOB date,
    MemberGender char(1),
    MemberChildren int,
    MemberStartDate date,
    CountryID int not null foreign key references country
) -- records all member information

create table mentor(
    MentorID int not null primary key Identity (1,1),
    MemberID int not null foreign key(MemberID) references member,
    MentorOnlineSynch char(1),
    MentorOnlineAsynch char(1),
    MentorPhoneSkype char(1),
    MentorFace char(1)
) -- mentor mentoring preferences

create table mentee(
    MenteeID int not null primary key Identity (1,1),
    MemberID int not null foreign key(MemberID) references member,
    MenteeOnlineSynch char(1),
    MenteeOnlineAsynch char(1),
    MenteePhoneSkype char(1),
    MenteeFace char(1)
) -- mentee mentoring preferences

create table pair(
    PairID int not null primary key Identity (1,1),
    MentorID int foreign key(MentorID) references mentor,
    MenteeID int foreign key(MenteeID) references mentee,
    PairStartDate date,
    PairEndDate date
) -- pair details which include mentor and mentee id's and the date they were paired
```

This is what creates Pairs now; however, it allows mentors and mentees to be in multiple pairs:

```
insert into Pair (mentorid, menteeid, pair.pairstartdate)
select mentor.mentorid, mentee.menteeid, getdate()
from mentor, mentee
left join pair on pair.menteeid = mentee.menteeid
where mentor.menteeonlinesynch = 'Y'
and mentee.mentoronlinesynch ='Y'
and mentor.menteeonlinesynch = mentee.mentoronlinesynch
and mentor.memberid !=m entee.memberid
```

Any ideas on how to fix it to allow a mentor to be in only one pair and a mentee to be in only one pair?

Comment: Judging from the syntax, this is sql-server and NOT mysql, correct?  I don't do sql-server but I think it has a ROW_NUMBER function that you might be able to use to pair up two shuffled lists.  Are you opposed to temp tables, stored procedures, nested queries, or anything else?  Are there guaranteed to be same number of mentors & mentees?

Comment: Just to clarify...You are expecting to have a one-to-one relationship. One member can be a mentor, but just for one and only one other member. Also, a member can only have one mentor.

Comment: A member can be a mentor and/or a mentee but in the pair it has to be two different members and no duplicate mentors or mentees. Does that clear it up?